Overfitting on the validation set
I’m working on a machine learning project where I have two datasets: X (features on individuals) and y (binary predictions: -1 or 1). My goal is to predict y based on the features in X.
Here’s a brief overview of the steps I’ve taken:

Preprocessing: I’ve preprocessed my feature set X accordingly.
Data Splitting: I randomly split the dataset into training and testing sets: X_train, X_test, y_train, and y_test.
Cross-Validation: I performed cross-validation on X_train and y_train using different values of k for
k-fold validation. In every case, I consistently obtained very high mean F1 scores during validation.
However, when I tested my model on X_test to predict y_pred and computed the F1 score against y_test, I also observed a similarly high F1 score.

I’ve tried several models, including least squares, ridge regression, and logistic regression.
My Questions:

Is it common or normal for the validation set to show such high scores while also yielding high scores on the test set?
What could be the reasons for this behavior? Could it indicate that my model is indeed overfitting?


The parameters learnt by the preprocessing stage should only be based on the training fold data$^\dagger$. If that condition isn't enforced, then you could end up with optimistic scores for the validation and test sets.
Assuming that part is okay, then reasons for a high test score could be:

The model is good at making accurate predictions (and/or the data is informative), leading to a high test score
The particular split of the test set is 'easy' this time, so you happen to get a very high score, but it is not necessarily representative of general performance.

Having a large and representative test set helps mitigate against the chances of the second scenario.
In general, one would expect the validation and test set scores to be lower than the training score, because the model hasn't seen the data. But this is more like a general tendency than a concrete rule.
$^\dagger$Building your preprocessing + modelling code as a scikit-learn pipeline helps prevent data leakage.
